# How the commission run in OFBiz work?

Tags: apache, erp, ofbiz

I am new with **OFBiz** and i am trying to understand the payment and invoice process .but i am stuck with the process of **"commission run"**.so far as ***i understand*** ,

1) party need to be created with "Sales rep"

2) when we create the invoice we need to add the "Sales rep" party to it

3) invoice need to be payed and in payed states to run this

but when i run it, it says  **Created Commission invoices for each commission receiving parties 0"**. so what am i missing ?
How to add the commission rate in the invoice ?
how is the output is given ?

Thanks All. for any input .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK i have run it :) ,i have not add products in Commission rate products. So as far as i understand it is the requirement for successful Commission run.

1)You need to create an Agreement with Agreement type = "Commission" from "X" to a Party(Y)      with role "Sales Representative"

2)You need to create an agreement item with type Commission rate

3)In agreement terms you can add Commission rules like "commission per unit" and create it

4)And you need to select the items you wish to put under there commission rates in Agreement products

5) You need to add an invoice with roles with "X" sales from Bill-From-Vendor and "Y" as Sales Representative

6) You need to bill the items you give rated and pay the invoice from payments and change the states to "payed"

If all of the above points are OK(make sure you have entered valid terms with generate a value), you can create the invoice automatically with commission run.